# How do i reset Safari 12 beforeunload events after pressing "Leave Page" without refreshing?

Tags: safari, oracle-apex

I have a webpage with a form on it, and a beforeunload event.

When the page first loads, if the form is changed, a confirmation message appears on both Safari and Chrome.

In Chrome - if i press "leave page" and then return to the page, future changes keep invoking the conformation upon attempt to leave the page.

In Safari - if i press "leave page" and then return to the page, future changes to the form don't invoke the message when leaving the page, and the target page is loaded without problems.
If i refresh the page, the confirmation "resets".

I develop using Oracle Apex 5.1, but according to different forums this happens regardless of the platform:
https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure/issues/112

Can you help me find a workaround?
Can i "Reset" safari without refreshing the page?